# Using Python to build Windows Phone 8 applications?

Tags: python, windows-phone-8

I've some stuff written in Python. I would like to implement the code as an app on WP8 platform. Any idea on how I can go about compiling Python for WP8?

I tried Googling, but that turned my brain into noodles. A link to a comprehensive tutorial would be nice as I'm not too familiar with developing applications on WP8.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with limitations on threading, according to this post: [Compiling Python for Windows Phone 8](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/515115/Compiling-Python-for-Windows-Phone-8)